# Display drawable in Sherlocklistfragment with custom layout

Tags: android, hashmap, actionbarsherlock, drawable

Im trying to display drawables from packages installed on the android device example: "com.android.browser" to show an icon for the application. 
I have setup an sherlocklistfragment with this layout

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/appName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numOpen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Then i use a hashmap to handle the data for the simpleAdapter

**Sherlocklistfragment**

```
public class List_fragment extends SherlockListFragment {
private PackageManager pk;
String[] apps = new String[] {
        "Browser",
        "Email",
        "Facebook",
        "Clock",
        "Map",
        "Calendar",
        "Settings",
        "Media player",
        "Google play",
        "testapp"
    };
String[] period = new String[]{
        "54",
        "23",
        "42",
        "23",
        "14",
        "23",
        "23",
        "1",
        "10",
        "12"
    };
public final static String TABLE_LOGS = "logs";
public final static String ID_COL = "_id";
public final static String DATE_COL = "date";
public final static String PACKAGE_COL = "package";
public final static String LAT_COL = "lat";
public final static String LNG_COL = "lng";
public final static String DUR_COL = "duration";
View view;
private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    List<HashMap<String,Object>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
    pk = getSherlockActivity().getPackageManager();
    Drawable drawable = null;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        hm.put("app", "" + apps[i]);
        hm.put("per", period[i] + " seconds");
        try {
            drawable = pk.getApplicationIcon("com.android.browser");
            //hm.put("image", drawable);
            hm.put("image", R.drawable.down_arrow);

        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        aList.add(hm);
    }
    Log.d("DRAWABLE", " "+ drawable);
    SimpleAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(inflater.getContext(), aList, 
             R.layout.list_layout, new String[] {"image", "app", "per"}, new int[] {R.id.imageView, R.id.appName, R.id.numOpen});
    //listAdapter.setViewBinder(mViewBinder);
    setListAdapter(listAdapter);
    Log.d("String " , " " + aList);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
private final SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder mViewBinder = new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {

    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,
            String textRepresentation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(view instanceof ImageView){
            ((ImageView) view).setImageDrawable((Drawable) data);
        }
        return false;
    }
};
 }
```

EDIT: code

This shows the text for appName and the arrow icon on imageview, BUT it doenst show the drawable i have inserted in the simple adapter? 
See this commented line:

```
 //hm.put("image", drawable);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There are may ways to do that, but first of all, your fragment layout should have a `ListView`.

> Screen Layout
>
> ListFragment has a default layout that consists of a single list view. However, if you desire, you can customize the fragment layout by returning your own view hierarchy from onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle). To do this, your view hierarchy must contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)
>
> Optionally, your view hierarchy can contain another view object of any type to display when the list view is empty. This "empty list" notifier must have an id "android:empty". Note that when an empty view is present, the list view will be hidden when there is no data to display. [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html)

As you are using a `SherlockListFragment` your layout must have `ListView` with a predefined `android:id=@android:id/list`

> Row Layout
>
> You can specify the layout of individual rows in the list. You do this by specifying a layout resource in the ListAdapter object hosted by the fragment (the ListAdapter binds the ListView to the data; more on this later).
>
> A ListAdapter constructor takes a parameter that specifies a layout resource for each row. It also has two additional parameters that let you specify which data field to associate with which object in the row layout resource. These two parameters are typically parallel arrays. [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html)

You must define the row layout using a separate **xml** or build it dynamic for
each  row. This first option is more commom.

As @Johannes said for `SimpleAdapter` you must have only `TextView`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554443/custom-list-item-to-listview-android) you can se a example with custom layout using only `TextView`. So you have to use/extends another `ListAdapter`, for instance a `ArrayAdapter` or even a `BaseAdapter`.

The most important thing about it is the method `getView`, which is the method responsible to
return the view which will be put on each line of your `ListView`. In this method, you will must inflate you row layout and fill it.

This link show a [complex custom layout example using BaseAdapter](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/). You can take a look at this link that show [basic custom layout](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_listviewexample) is is better to understand what exactly you have to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't figure out how this would help me with assign the drawable android.graphics.drawable.bitmapdrawables to the simple adapter or the imageview of a given layout file. The link with the nice list view of music artists doesn't have a solution to my problem. This still "just" takes a resource from the drawable.
Correct me i im wrong.

Furthermore why do i need a listview to display a custom list view? The list are showing but only with textviews. Is it really necessary to use listview when using a adapter with images? Sorry but I'm a little confused.

Comment: The main point of your question is, you must implement a custom list layout because Android provides adapters only for basic list. To put a specific drawable on your list, you should implement the method getView of a ListAdapter. This is independent of your drawable, if it is a resource drawable or not. This does not matter. If your problem is get correctly the drawable, i think you should change your question. Correct me if i am wrong, you don't have a list, you have a LinearLayout right?

Comment: Ok, I might have been a bit unclear in my explanation. I do get a list showing text and images, but only images as a resource ex: R.drawable.arrow. 

See new inserted code

What i want to do is to get the icon for a application installed on the device using the following.

drawable = pk.getApplicationIcon("com.android.browser");

If try with the drawable from the above it get this message: 

resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@40694728

Comment: If I need to make my own custom adapter, then can you guys help how best to do so?

Answer (score 0):

From [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#SimpleAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20?%3E%3E,%20int,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29)

For Parameter **to** (the last one, your imageView1 and textView1:

> The views that should display column in the "from" parameter. **These should all be TextViews.** The first N views in this list are given the
>   values of the first N columns in the from parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem now. Thanks for the help.

With the use of http://android-er.blogspot.dk/2012/03/display-video-thumbnail-on-listfragment.html I have created a row.xml layout file and a custom cursor adapter as follows:

**Cursor adapter**

```
 public class MyCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{
    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,     int[] to){
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = getSherlockActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        TextView text1 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        TextView text2 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        ImageView image1 = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        Cursor cursor = adapter.getCursor();
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        try {
            info =    pk.getApplicationInfo(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PACKAGE_COL)), 0);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String title = (String) pk.getApplicationLabel(info);
        text1.setText(title);
        String duration = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DUR_COL));
        text2.setText("App open for " + duration + " seconds");

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
          options.inDither = false;
          options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
          Drawable d = info.loadIcon(pk);
          image1.setImageDrawable(d);


          return row;
    }
}
```

**Layout**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >
 <LinearLayout 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal">

 <ImageView
 android:id="@+id/image1"
 android:layout_width="75dp"
 android:layout_height="75dp"
 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
 <LinearLayout 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical">
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/text1"
 android:textSize="22dp"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/text2"
 android:textSize="18dp"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 </LinearLayout>



 </LinearLayout>
 <ImageView
 android:id="@+id/image2"
 android:layout_width="40dp"
 android:layout_height="40dp"
 android:src="@drawable/arrow"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  />
 </RelativeLayout>
```